# Assassin/Fantasy Novel with Tree of Blades test

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trying to find help finding a fantasy book. Unfortunately, I only really remember one scene;

- The main character is male, and travels to a distant region with a society of people who speak a different language. His goal is to train his martial and sword skills. This society is built around their fighting skills, where more skilled fighters are more respected.
- His trainer is a female character who is a bit of an outcast herself. He finds that they all believe he can't cut it in their training/tests, including the trainer. The trainer is really harsh with him, as are most people in this society due to the fact that the main character is a foreigner.
- I believe his first real test involved crossing the area beneath this large tree with leaves like blades to touch the trunk of the tree without dying. The leaves are closer together and more difficult to cross the closer you get to the trunk.
- I think that at first, when he tries, he gets a bunch of cuts. He thinks the challenge is impossible. Then he sees one of the children of the village just dancing between those branches and leaves on the outskirts of the tree without getting hurt. He does finally get through the leaves and ends up doing it with no injuries at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is *[The Wise Man's Fear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wise_Man%27s_Fear)* by Patrick Rothfuss, the second book of *The Kingkiller Chronicle*.

Kvothe trains with the Adem people.

> Upon reuniting with his mercenary companions, he learns that only three days have passed in the mortal world. On the return trip to Severen, one of the mercenaries, an Adem warrior named Tempi, is ordered to stand trial for teaching Kvothe the Ketan, a secretive form of martial arts; Kvothe accompanies Tempi to the distant country of Ademre, where he completes his training in the Ketan and in the Lethani philosophy to justify Tempi's teaching him. Upon passing a series of final tests, Kvothe is rewarded with an ancient sword he names Caesura, and an Adem legend regarding the names and signs of the "Rhinta"—known to Kvothe as the Chandrian.

His final test is to navigate the [Sword Tree](https://kingkiller.fandom.com/wiki/Latantha).

> The Latantha (PR: /lɛt'ɑn.ðə/), or Sword Tree, is a species of tree native to Ademre. It is sacred to the Adem people, and gives its name to the school of fighting based in Haert.
>
> ....
>
> The Latantha is notable for several reasons, the most obvious of which is that Kvothe was taught in this school. Also, even though most warriors belong to only one school, the latantha accepted a very proficient fighter Vashet, Kvothe's teacher, into the school despite the fact that she had been previously taught through the Path of Joy.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that's the one. Funny I forgot this scene is in the king killer chronicles. Been so long since I've been waiting for that third book.

Comment: @Ben: You can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: And yeah... I'm not holding my breath about the third book. He's been at it so long, with no visible sign of progress, that I think he's blocked.